# Laptop for developers (2017)

Tags: laptop, development

Im looking for a laptop as a mostly backend developer. i did some research but there is a few gaps in my knowledge.

Specs:

- price €1000 - 1500
- Super fast processor, needs to run console applications + web + Visual studio/Rider and VS code.
- Screen of +1080p  * 16gb+ memory, (for all the docker containers). (Will DDR4 Bring performance?)
- SSD only (258GB is enough)
- Graphics cards only if needed to render visual studio/Rider, otherwise rather use Intel Grapics.
- Windows does not need to be installed. (Rather without, i'll probably run on linux)
- its light, so i can take it anywhere.

## Processor

For processors i ended up with:

- Ci7-6700HQ
- Ci7-7700HQ (10% faster)

They are both quad and 8 threads (great for running these multiple applications).

### Found laptops

- MSI GP62M 7RD-014NL (Leopard) €1200
- HP 15-ax235nd  (Omen) €1400

But my problem is that all these laptops are build and promoted as gaming laptops. I'm looking for a work laptop which i can take anywhere and doesn't really look like a gaming laptop.

All i'm looking for is fast processor, ssd and memory. Are there laptops specifically build for this?

Comment: Technically gaming laptops are just high power laptops that can be customized.  I have an MSI GL62 (lower down the line than the GP series)  I mainly do college course work on it (OpenBSD, Ubuntu, VMs, etc).  While it does have the horsepower for gaming, and I do game on it, this is not the main reason why I bought it.  Max ram capacity of 32GB, and other upgrade paths are always good.    As far as a no OS option, Sager usually gives that option.  I will find/configure one and post as an answer.  But to close, most customization comes on enthusiast/gaming level items.

Comment: Also.....do you prefer a 14" 15" or 17" notebook?

Comment: @NZKshatriya 15" preferable, i think, ive never worked on 17". although the screen is bigger im not sure i would be satisfied with size/mobility

Comment: Mine is 15.6" weighs in at around 5.5Lbs (i think)   I really don't notice the weight, though I am carrying around a backpack with the notebook, three textbooks, charger, lunch and a couple 20oz sodas each day.....Total weight easily above 20Lbs lol.

Comment: To be completely honest, I have seen a lot of posts as of late with professionals asking for high spec notebooks for video editing, or virtual machines, or other job based duties. (and all saying no gaming machines...my mentality is a box is a box lol)  A couple were really disconnected from reality, either in budget being way too low, or in thinking they could get a high performance system in a thin <4Lb setup.  I've also seen a real gap between some higher reputation StackOverflow users(programmers) and basic hardware knowledge *which scares me*

Comment: @NZKshatriya why wouldn't there be something like this? a box is always more then just a box. I found the Lenovo IdeaPad 700-15ISK, which looks very promising (they seem to be able to do it pretty well). ill do some more research before i decide.

Comment: Well if its a blue box with the words police call box on it, then of course its more than just a box :P

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the [Sager NP3245](https://www.sagernotebook.com/customize.php?productid=1157)

A configuration of a 256Gb m.2 SSD as the OS drive and storage drives leaves room for future upgrades.

Does not come with a discrete GPU, but uses the on chip Intel graphics.

Has 8Gb, 16Gb, 32Gb Ram options.

Has other customization options, at the buyers discretion.

Comment: This was the only one I could find without a discrete GPU :(,   Anyway, have to get ready to drive cross town for a Japanese 1 course....yay rush hour traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Sager, i see they have a lot of options. Which greatly helps me to calculate costs and opertunities

Comment: Yeah, I posted this recommendation before you stated a preference for a 15"  system.  These systems typically are aimed at the enthusiast/gaming segment of the market, but the plethora of options really benefit all applications.